# Showing time translation and a general rotation are symmetries of a given Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, noethers-theorem

> Given a "free particle" Lagrangian:
>   $$
> L=\frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{dq}{dt}\right)^2,
> $$
>
> (a) Show that $t \rightarrow t'= t+s$ is a symmetry of $L$.
>
> (b) Show that $q \rightarrow q'= Rq$ s a symmetry of $L$ for $R\in SO(3)$.

- Definition: A transformation is a symmetry $\Leftrightarrow$ 
  $$
  L'= L+\frac{d}{dt}M.
  $$

The main problem I'm having in (a) is understanding how the time translation affects $\frac{dq}{dt}$ (i.e. what is $(\frac{dq}{dt})'$ ?).

For (b) my problem comes in computing $(R \frac{dq}{dt})^2$ since all I know is that $R\in SO(3)$. And if I just write $R^2$, I can't show that the rotation is a symmetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part:
$$
\frac{d}{dt'}=\frac{d}{dt} \frac{dt}{dt'}= \frac{d}{dt}
$$
by the chain rule.

For the second part, $\dot{q}^2\to (\dot{\vec{q}})^T\dot{\vec{q}}=  \sum_i \dot{q}_i^2$ 
with $\dot{\vec{q}}=\left(\begin{array}{c}\dot{q}_1\\ \vdots \\ \dot{q}_n\end{array}\right)$ when there are $n$ generalized coordinates so under rotation
$$
(\dot{\vec{q}'})^T \dot{\vec{q}'}= (\dot{\vec{q}})^T R^T R\dot{\vec{q}}=
 (\dot{\vec{q}})^T \dot{\vec{q}}
$$
since  $R^T R=\boldsymbol{\hbox{I}}$ for rotations.